# iterating and storing object equal to itself

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me in understanding the reason why someone would iterate when it's value is equal to it?

for example

```
let subStyle = {
      width: 300,
      height: 50,
      borderRadius: 20,
      backgroundColor:  theme.primaryBlue
    };

subStyle = {
        ...subStyle,
        backgroundColor: theme.primaryWhite,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: '#707070'
      }
```

i.e in the above code, what could be the reason for doing the same?

```
subStyle = {
        ...subStyle,
        backgroundColor: theme.primaryWhite,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: '#707070'
      }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're copying the properties from the object `subStyle` refers to into a new object (then overwriting one of them and adding two more), then assigning that new object to the `subStyle` variable. This is quite standard when you aren't allowed to modify the original object because something else may be using it ([React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) state, for instance).

Simpler example:

```js
let o1 = {a: "ay", b: "bee"};
let o2 = o1; // Something else is using the same object

// We need to create a new, updated object without
// affecting others who have access to the current one
o1 = {...o1, b: "BEE", c: "see"};

// The original is unchanged
console.log(o2);

// The new one has the updates
console.log(o1);
```

That `...someObject` within an object initializer is called *property spread*. It was added to JavaScript in ES2018.

I should note that it's not iteration in JavaScript terms (though of course it's similar) and it doesn't require that the object be iterable. (In constrast, `...` in an array initializer *is* iteration and *does* require that what you use it on be iterable.)

Answer (score 2):

Because let's say you want to update that object in an immutable way. The mutable way would be:

```
let x = {a:1, b:2};
x.a=123;
```

Immutable way, you create a new object, [copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) properties of old one using ... operator (in a shallow way), and also assign a new property (or overwrite existing one):

```
let x = {a:1, b:2};
let y = {...x, a:123} // We created a new object and copied properties from x to it, also update value of a
```

This way you get object with same contents as in the first example, but you didn't modify `x`.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially for keeping the same values in the object.
When you do `subStyle = { ... }` you are overwriting the object.

If you do `subStyle = { ...subStyle }` you will copy all you had before inside `subStyle` and the rest that you add will be added along

An illustrative example:

```js
let myObject = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b'
}

console.log('My object: ', myObject)

myObject = { ...myObject }

console.log('Copying my object with spread operator: ', myObject)

myObject = { 
  ...myObject,
  c: 'c',
  d: 'd'
}

console.log('Adding new elements to my copied object with spread operator: ', myObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is called [Destructuring_assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). It allows to unpack objects into bunch of variables.

Let `subStyle1` be a new variable. That `...` will allow to copy the properties from the `subStyle`  to `subStyle1`

```js
let subStyle = {
  width: 300,
  height: 50,
  borderRadius: 20,
  backgroundColor: 'theme.primaryBlue'
};

let subStyle1 = {
  ...subStyle,
  backgroundColor: 'theme.primaryWhite',
  borderWidth: 2,
  borderColor: '#707070'

};

console.log(subStyle1)
```

Comment: No, this isn't destructuring assignment. It's using property spread syntax in an object initializer. ([*PropertyDefinition: ...AssignmentExpression*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object-initializer)). Destructuring would be on the other side of the `=`. (Just terminology, the explanation is correct.)